# How to Multiply a column value based on a list of ID numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset and want to times a value column by 2.5 based on the ID value of a list.

My data frame looks like this

```
  Name    ID   Salary 
  James   21   25,000
  Sam     12   15,000
```

My list is a series and let's call it s = ["21", "36"] this data is the ID numbers

How do I get it based on the ID number to times the salary by 2.5?

The goal is to have something like this

```
  Name    ID   Salary 
  James   21   62,500
  Sam     12   15,000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert `Salary` to numeric and then convert values of `ID` to strings, test by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and multiple by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select rows by mask and column by name `Salary`:

```
s = ["21", "36"]

#if values of Salary are strings
#df = pd.read_csv(file, thousands=',')
#or
#df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)

#ID are converted to strings by `astype`, because valus in list s are strings
df.loc[df['ID'].astype(str).isin(s), 'Salary'] *= 2.5
#if s are numeric
#df.loc[df['ID'].isin(s), 'Salary'] *= 2.5
print (df)
    Name  ID   Salary
0  James  21  62500.0
1    Sam  12  15000.0
```

Comment: what if my salary is a float64?

Comment: @amythomspon - Then omit `df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)`